# CircleCI & Golang - Can't import AWS SDK

Tags: github, go, aws-sdk, circleci, aws-sdk-go

I'm not sure whether this is the right place to post such question.

I was trying to test my golang project on CircleCI. In the phase of `dependencies`, CI executed

```
go get -u github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/...
```

And there occurred an error:

```
package github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/...
    imports github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws
    imports github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr: /home/ubuntu/sprocket-analytics-data-pipeline-v2/src/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go is from git@github.com:aws/aws-sdk-go, should be from https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go
```

The error was very long, and the code above is just a part of it.

So, I updated my `circleci.yml` to override the dependencies phase. The `circleci.yml` is like:

```
machine:
  timezone:
    Asia/Tokyo
  environment:
    GOPATH: /home/ubuntu/my-project/src/go
dependencies:
  override:
    - go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
    - go get github.com/google/google-api-go-client/bigquery/v2
    - go get code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth/jwt
    - go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/cover
    - go get github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml
    - go get github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report
    - go get github.com/golang/mock/gomock
    - go get github.com/onsi/gomega
    - go get github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo
    - go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/...
    - go get github.com/axw/gocov/...
test:
  pre:
    - go install path/to/the/package
  override:
    - go test /home/ubuntu/my-project/src/go/src/path/to/the/package
```

The `go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/...` in my config worked fine.

However, after all the commands in my `circleci.yml` had been executed, `go get -u github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/...` was executed anyway by the CI. And it failed again with the same error.

Here is the log from CircleCI:

[image]

Is there any walk-around for this? Or did I miss something, like configuring the address to get the go packages(according to the error messages)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your circle.yml file. This should force an SSH checkout rather than a http one.

```
checkout:
  post:
    - git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

You should then be able to remove all of your dependency overrides.

CircleCI also has a nice feature where you can rebuild with an SSH connection. Try running the commands manually inside the container if you have problems with debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried to force git use `git@github.com` to checkout, and remove all the dependency overrides. The problem is still there. I think the problem here is that the go command `go get` only allow users to use https to get packages in go 1.4. Here is a [reference](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8850). This limit seems to be removed since 1.4.1 according to [https://github.com/gliderlabs/herokuish/pull/6]. And I used ssh to access to the circleci box and managed go-get via `go get -u -f`, so I think figuring out a way to use https on circleci is the way out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a walk-around for this.

It seems that CircleCI is using go 1.4, which did not allow people to use `git@github.com` to make `go get -u`, unless you use `go get -u -f`.
So I figured trying to use https to do the `go get -u` is the only way currently.

[ref: issue #8850](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8850)

And CircleCI has its own configuration on `git` in `~/.gitconfig` to force git to use `git@github.com` instead of https:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

If you access to the box of CircleCI via ssh, you can find this file.

[ref](https://github.com/gliderlabs/herokuish/pull/6)

So, my way is:

Rename this file in the phase of **dependencies-pre**, and let dependencies phase finish, Then rename it back if you still need those configurations.

Now `go get -u` works fine no matter whether you add it in the `circle.yml` file or it is executed automatically by CircleCI.